# Windows Phone 8.1: Scrollbar of ListView is not visible

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1, scrollbar

In our Windows Phone 8.1 application we have added a ListView with custom list item template.
We can scroll the list view but it doesn't show the vertical scroll bar.

We have tried with setting below property of ListView

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Can you try using a tool like Xaml Spy to see if the width of the listview is not larger then the screen real estate? Maybe it's there, but just not visible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is fixed by setting the lighter theme to the ListView.

```
<ListView RequestedTheme="Light"/>
```

I am not sure what was the reason behind it but this worked. The scroll bar is now visible when we start scrolling.

We have our own custom theme and not using Accent color so this will not make any issue in our code.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code add the vertical scroll mode = "TRUE"

```
<ListView
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="True"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="True"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try adding listviewitems to the listview you can directly scroll the list items in your phone emulator but when we drap our mouse to scroll then the scroll viewer will be visible. Check it once
Else elaborate your question more clearly

Comment: I mentioned we can scroll but it doesn't show the scroll bar. Please note ListView has more number of items such that we need to scroll to see all the items, scrolling is working but it isn't showing scroll bar.

Comment: I think using list view control it is not possible